# Why bean is not created?

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

My problem:
Why Spring autoscan is not working for me?
  I prefer not to use `bean.xml` file but rather make the system scan the beans by itself.
I use Spring `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.
 The bean has a `@Component` annotation and its package is included in the `scan`, but when trying to get the bean there is `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

I have a maven project in the following structure

```
 - module A  
 - module B (depends on A)   
 - module C (depends on B)
```

(Initiating by `@Configuration` class is also a problem since the code to initiate application context is generic in `module A` and the bean are in `module B` and cannot be instantiated from A.)

In `module A` there is a code to load `ApplicationContext`.
I have one singelton for getting the application context.

```java
    package com.mycode.my;

    public class AppContext {
       private static ApplicationContext ctx;

       public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
          if (ctx == null)
            ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("com.mycode");
        return ctx;
       }
    }
```

In module B there is interface and bean using it

```java
    package com.mycode.third;
    public interface MyBean{
       void runSomething();
    }


    package com.mycode.third; 
    @Component   
    public class MyBeanImpl implements MyBean{
       public void runSomething(){
       }
    }
```

The problem:
When I try from module C to get a bean:

```java
    public class MyImpl{
       public void doTheJob(){
          MyBean bean1 = AppContext.getApplicationContext().getBean("myBean") 
       }
    }
```

I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException
```

Any idea how to make it work or better approach?

Comment: Your bean is created, it just isn't named "myBean". Because you haven't given it any name, Spring is likely used something like `MyBeanImpl` as the bean name. `@Component` annotation supports giving bean a name, use that.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the bean name of a component (or any other bean stereotype) is : the class name with a lowercase as first letter.  So your bean is named `myBeanImpl`.
Here you specify the interface name as bean name in your lookup.
It doesn't work in this way because if the interface was used by Spring as bean name,  you could not have multiple implementations of that.

> Any idea how to make it work or better approach?

A better approach is not using directly the spring factory to get a bean but injecting it with autowiring feature.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyAppConfig.class) 
public class MyImpl{

   private MyBean bean;

   // Autowire constructor
   public MyImpl(MyBean bean){
     this.bean = bean;
   }
   public void doTheJob(){
      // you can use bean now
   }
}
```

A still better is using Spring Boot that relies you some additional configuration as long as you respect the standards.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find by `myBean` name add as [value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html) to Component:

```
@Component("myBean")   
public class MyBeanImpl implements MyBean {
```

> The value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component name, to be turned into a Spring bean in case of an autodetected component.

Or get by class instead of String value

```
getAppContext().getBean(MyBean.class);
```